# how can I debug an angular select (or any other type) binding that is failing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got about 5 bindings on a page that look similar to:

```
<select ng-options="d as (d.display || d.name) for d in products" 
ng-model="customer.products" class="ib ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
  ...
</select>
```

(I munged the options/model a bit to protect IP, but that's very close)

The problem is that one of the five is not selecting the option that corresponds to its model. When I compare the ng-model to the correct option using:

```
JSON.stringify(s.products[9]) == 
  JSON.stringify(s.customer.products) // s is the scope for the select
```

I get `true`. The object in the options list and the model are equivalent, but the binding isn't happening, so they aren't equivalent enough.

The ng-options declaration looks correct to me. I'd like to dig into the angular code and figure out why A != B when the binding is happening. Where is that? I've found the `var selectDirective = ['$compile', '$parse', function($compile,   $parse) {` (line 17523 angular 1.2.0) code, that's close but that doesn't appear to be where the connection between a potential select value and the currently selected value happens.

What portion of the angular code is used when select options and the model are "connected"?

Comment: Perhaps, instead of digging so deep in Angular internals, you should try and reproduce the problem in a plunker. I'm sure you'd get your answer in no time.

Comment: Well I was thinking reading the code would be good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/e415e916e85040fe62c801092be698ab06c1d11c/src/ng/directive/select.js#L458) sets the initial selected option:

```
selected = modelValue === valueFn(scope, locals);
```

I think you are also setting your "not selected" option incorrectly, as per the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect):

> Optionally, a single hard-coded  element, with the value set
>   to an empty string, can be nested into the  element. This
>   element will then represent the null or "not selected" option.

You can view the source to only the select directive over [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/e415e916e85040fe62c801092be698ab06c1d11c/src/ng/directive/select.js).

Other than that it's difficult to give any other input without seeing a plunker or fiddle illustrating the problem.

Comment: '<option value="?"' is being generated by angular. Thanks for the pointer to the render function, that looks like what I needed.

Comment: That helped, but now I'm wondering if this is a bug because: `JSON.stringify(valueFn(scope, locals)) == JSON.stringify(modelValue) ` is returning true. But the objects aren't equal. Shouldn't angular be doing a bit of deep-equal checking here? I ran `lodash.isEqual(modelValue, valueFn(scope, locals))` and got `true`.

Comment: (same for `angular.equals(modelValue, valueFn(scope, locals))`)

Comment: @jcollum I typically use my objects IDs as values and not the whole object, so I haven't run into this issue before.